# How to use Notepad++ on Redhat?

Tags: notepad++, redhat-enterprise-linux

I want to use Notepad++ on my RedHat machine. But there is no setup file available for Linux.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [run Notepad++ using Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2983), but there is no shortage of excellent text editors for Linux. Why not try Kate, if you're on KDE, or Bluefish if you're on Gnome?

Comment: Was gonna say that too :-) Although I noticed that running Notepad++ in Wine was really slow for me.

Comment: I have reached this page: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=13036&iTestingId=48121 Now how do I download??

Comment: Linux handles software installations differently from Windows. Instead of downloading .exe files and installing them directly, Linux centralises software installations in a package manager. Redhat should have an  "add/remove software" option in the menus. Use that to find an advanced text editor or wine. Which version of Redhat are you on?

Comment: how do I check the redhat version?

Comment: Click on the winehq link, then the URL link for the SourceForge page. Click on download at the top of the page and click on Binary Files, then click on Download Notepad++ executable files, and click on the link to npp.5.6.4.bin.zip Save the ZIP file and extract the contents. Now, unfortunately, you're on your own because I'm using Unbuntu 9.10 and I just had to click on `notepad++.exe` to start it in Wine. I don't know how you start Wine on Redhat. It may be just as simple.

Comment: You should be able to check the Redhat version by looking through your system application menus to find an **About** screen. It's there, but it will take some hunting.

Comment: cat /etc/redhat-release, but that is on RHEL (Redhat Enterprise Linux) systems, othernwise, you can try uname -r (this does not always give a release number).